# 64-bit and 32-bit integers

Tags: c++

Is there a good way to modify a class in C++ so that its integers are 64-bit on a 64-bit system and 32-bit for 32-bit systems? Is there a way to check for that?

The class is something like:

```
class B{
      public:
            int64_t size();
      private:
            int64_t m_size();
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe that this is desirable?

Comment: Predefined compiler macros and header files are worth here .

Comment: I agree with Ignacio here, it's almost always better to use fixed size types, you'll be prone to less errors then (for example serialization...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want exactly what you said (32-bit on 32-bit and 64-bit on 64-bit) you'll need to use macros.

But what you probably want instead is to just use `size_t`.

EDIT:

`size_t` is guaranteed to be large enough to size any object and index any array. And as such, it is usually 32-bits on 32-bit and 64-bits on 64-bit. So it probably does exactly what you want.

Comment: The OP never specified signed or unsigned. But based on the way it's being used, I'm going guess that unsigned is suitable.

Comment: or just `long` which is 32 bits on x86 & 64 bits on x86-64 with `gcc`. Or Perhaps some of the "fast" types in `<stdint.h>` ?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: It doesn't hold in Windows though. `long` is always 32-bits in Windows - even on x64.

Comment: @Nim, there is also `ssize_t`.

Comment: @SimonRichter: `ptrdiff_t` is the standard signed type for pointer offsets. `ssize_t` is a Posix type, and usually means "size or error code" rather than a signed offset.

Answer (score 2):

There is `intptr_t`, which can be used for the nefarious purposes you probably have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `long int`. AFAIK `long int` is the same as `int` (4 byte integer) in 32-bit compilers and the same as `long long int` (8 byte integer) in 64-bit compilers. You can check it with `sizeof`.